# "Compound nouns list" or "compound noun list"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, nouns

I couldn't help but wonder every time I saw such a noun phrase. I've seen both forms used equally often, so I guess both of them can be used interchangeably. But do I guess right?

Some examples:

> Here is a frequently used *compound nouns list*.
>
> Here is a frequently used *compound noun list*.

I usually rephrase them into something like this.

> Here is a reference *list* of *compound nouns*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All are correct.

But are the compound nouns frequently used, or is the list frequently used?

If it's important to state 'frequently', here are some possible alternatives:

If the compound nouns are frequently used:

> Here is a list of frequently used compound nouns.

> Here is a list of compound nouns that are frequently used.

If the list is frequently used:

> Here is a list of compound nouns, that is frequently used.

> Here is a frequently used list of compound nouns. (this one still slightly ambiguous)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What I wonder now is that, if all are correct, which is the one a native speaker would use naturally?

BTW, is there any implication (such as American dialect vs. English dialect or social/educational backgrounds) we can deduce from each usage?

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all, which is asking about the correctness of using a plural-form attributive noun here. _donkey sanctuary v donkeys sanctuary // dog home v dogs home_

Answer (score 0):

I will ignore the context of the examples, which John discussed. To get a better feeling, I would use simpler examples, e.g. a *verb list* vs. a *verbs list*. The former seems to be preferable, so I would prefer *compound noun list*.
BTW: the segmentation of the compound would be ((compound noun) list), which makes it parallel to (verb list).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Like **donkey sanctuary** v donkeys sanctuary. But then we have dog home v **dogs home**. // The default choice for an attributive noun being the singular form (though the usages aren't count: *'a 3 [-] dogs home') has been thoroughly addressed in other threads.