# How to correctly write chains of nouns with plurals like "Messages List" and "Apple Count" for IT

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number, programming, attributive-nouns, of-genitive

Especially in IT it is often neccessary to write chains of nouns like *messages list* because one cannot use *list of messages* for a variable name in a programming language.

I can't understand how to construct them correctly for plurals, for example is it a "message list" or "messages list"? What grammar rules concern this subject?

As a maybe special case, I'm interesting in naming the number of something, for example the number of apples. It is common to use "apple count" (although *count* means counting, not quantity). What is right, "apple count" or "apples count", and why?

I found [a little bit similar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36369/compound-nouns-list-or-compound-noun-list) question. Maybe both forms are allowed?

Comment: Why do you think it is somehow impossible to use noun phrases like `list_of_messages` instead of only compound nouns like `message_list` in a programming context? People do this all the time by using full phrases in real English, whether that means *Verb Phrases* for **function names** like `tentatively_mark_messages_for_deletion`, or *Noun Phrases* for **variable names** like `messages_marked_for_deletion` or even `expired_messages_marked_for_deletion_after_midnight`. Sticking as close to real English as possible for identifiers ***greatly*** improves code readability!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the plural would be odd, if not outright wrong.

- A list of messages is a *message list*, not a *messages list*.
- A trap for mice is a *mouse trap*, not a *mice trap*.
- A catcher of flies is a *flycatcher*, not a *fliescatcher*.
- Determination of types of compound nouns is *compound noun type determination*, not *compound nouns types determination*.

Answer (score 3):

There are [plenty of discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions) about this topic already, which could be considered a grey area between English and programming, I guess.

As an English-speaking programmer, I'd suggest that such names would generally contain singular nouns, such as messageList and appleCount in your case (capitalisation is a whole other issue and possibly a massive can of worms!)

The general idea behind naming things in this way is so that other people (and you in the future) can understand what's going on at a glance.  I've had to work with C++ code with single-letter variable names (ostensibly chosen for compiler efficiency) and it's not pleasant.

So as long as the code is clear, then I'm not sure it matters too much.  You could actually have theListOfMessages, but you're going to be typing more and could 'clutter' the code.  Try to keep them short and meaningful.  If you're doing this professionally, your employer may well have their own guidelines which could indeed contradict some of my comments above.

Comment: Although incorrect , I have used "merchandises" in my code, just to imply that it is a one to many relationship. My coworkers have found it helpful. I suspect this question will be marked irrelevant but that's my two cents for you.

Comment: @Ritu : That's a good point.  Languages like Ruby actively encourage this convention, I believe.  (I've never used it).

Comment: I think this answers a different question.